# Is there any frame throttle callback in XCB?

Tags: x11, xcb, wayland

I would like to write a 3D program on XCB and I would like to put my "render_frame" function into the frame throttle callback. However, I don't know what is the frame throttle callback in XCB. Is there any equivalent of “WM_PAINT”(Win32) / “wl_surface::frame”(wayland) in XCB?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the Present extension. Google just gave me https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/presentproto/tree/presentproto.txt, but this describes version 1.0 of the extension. The current version is 1.2, so somewhere there should be a newer documentation. I do not know what the additions since version 1.0 are and whether you need them.

Comment: I don't know what is the frame throttle callback in XCB

Comment: Is there any equivalent of “WM_PAINT”(Win32) / “wl_surface::frame”(wayland) in XCB?

Comment: Yes, the Present extension provides events for that.

Comment: Well, and since I have not said so explicitly yet: Core X11 does not have anything like that.

Comment: How to use that extension by libXCB?